# When the positive integers are colored, prove there exist three numbers whose sums are all the same color.

Tags: combinatorics

Each positive integer is colored either red, blue and green. Show that there always exists distinct positive integers $a,b,c$ such that $a,b,c,a+b,b+c,a+c,a+b+c$ are all of the same color.